# Java getting certain bytes from a long

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a method that takes an integer `n`, and two longs `x` and `y`. It should return the first `n` bytes from `x`, and the rest from `y`. Seems simple enough but I am new to working directly with bytes and cannot get this method to work.

```
public static long nBytesFromXRestY(int n, long x, long y) {
    int yl = longToBytes(y).length;
    byte[] xx = new byte[yl];
    byte[] xa = longToBytes(x);
    byte[] yb = longToBytes(y);
    for (int i=0;i<xx.length;i++) {
        if (i < n) {
            System.out.println("i < n");
            xx[i] = xa[i];
        } else {
            xx[i] = yb[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xx));
    return bytesToLong(xx);
}
```

If I feed that method for `n = 3`, `x = 45602345`, and `y = 10299207`, it should return `45699207` (right..?) but it will return `10299207`..

It prints `"i < n"` three times so I know the for and if/else are working. Yet for some reason it still just returns the `yb` array. Sorry if this is a stupid question.. New concept for me.

EDIT: `longToBytes` and `bytesToLong` methods:

```
public static long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);  
    buffer.put(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    buffer.flip();//need flip 
    return buffer.getLong();
}

public static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    buffer.putLong(0, x);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing bytes with digits. In your wanted output, you take the first 3 digits of `x` followed by the rest of `y`.

Comment: Okay, I had a feeling that's what is was. So what _should_ this method be returning if I feed it those same numbers and it uses the first 3 bytes, not digits?

Comment: Exactly the result you have. Print `longToBytes(45602345)` and `longToBytes(10299207)`, you'll see that the "first" 3 of are all 0.

Comment: Huh okay, why is there always four 0's as the first 4 bytes when I convert a long to a byte[] ?

Comment: You're not using big enough numbers, or you're not using the `L` suffix to force the use of long literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitshifting instead of creating objects.

```
public static long nBytesFromXRestY(int n, long x, long y) {
    long mask = ~0L << (n * 8);
    return (x & mask) | ( y & ~mask);
}
```

This will return the lowest n * 8 bits of `y` and the higher bits of x.

http://ideone.com/1CkqYT

Prints as expected.

```
45299207
```